# How can I use a view from different class?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I've searched a lot this but I really did not find what I need exactly.

### What I want is :

I have a listview and load it on my `main` class. I load it like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this,
                    R.layout.myrow,R.id.text ); 
            if (friends != null) {
                for (ParseObject friend : friends) {
                    adapter.add((String) friend.get("name"));
                }
            }
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and `myrow` layout xml is here:

```
< RelativeLayout   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/my_prog"
    ></ProgressBar>
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"  
    android:textSize="25sp" >

</TextView>

</RelativeLayout >
```

You can see I have progress bar on `textview` so I need to reach it and set it's **visible.**  I mean sometimes I set it **invisible** sometimes **visible**

### What I did is:

On my **MainActivity** `on create method` the code is here :

```
ProgressBar my_prog;
my_prog=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.my_prog);
my_prog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

### The error is:

```
07-16 13:35:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(29096): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{....MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I think I cant reach **my_prog** on my main activity but I need it.

How can I do that.

thanks in adnvace...

Comment: You need to keep the reference of the parent view (view holder) and then find its child (progress bar) inorder to perform any operation on it.

Comment: Are you using a listview?

Comment: yep I use a listview on my main.xml but you can see the adapter how can I load it , and how can I use view holder?

Comment: You need to know about notify data set changes in order to change listview. Parent view reference would be a very dangerous thing in this case.

Comment: I do not want to change listview status or anything , I need to hide or show progressbar on every row on listview

Comment: You've got your ans below..... that is the best way to get things done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a custom `Adapter` to do this. I have written this `ExampleAdapter` to show you how it works, I commented all the important parts:

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final List<ParseObject> objects;
    private final boolean[] activated;

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> objects) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.objects = objects;
        this.activated = new boolean[objects.size()]; 
    }

    public void showProgressBar(int position, boolean visible) {
        this.activated[position] = visible;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ParseObject getItem(int position) {
        return this.objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // If the convertView is null, we need to inflate a new one
        if(convertView == null) {
            // We inflate the view with your layout
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myrow, parent, false);

            // Here we create a view holder object which keeps a 
            // reference to the Views in this row so we have to
            // perform the expensive findViewById() only once
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.my_prog = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_prog);

            // The view holder is set as tag to the view so we can access it later
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        // We retrieve the ParseObject for the current position
        ParseObject parseObject = getItem(position);

        // And get the view holder from the View
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        // We read the data we need from the ParseObject
        String name = parseObject.get("name");

        // And here is the visibility logic
        int progressBarVisibility = this.activated[position] ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
        int textViewVisibility = this.activated[position] ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;

        // Now we set the data to the Views through the view holder
        holder.text.setText(name);
        holder.text.setVisibility(textViewVisibility);
        holder.my_prog.setVisibility(progressBarVisibility);

        return convertView;
    }

    // This is our view holder class. It keeps a reference to the Views 
    // inside each row so we have to perform the expensive
    // findViewById() only once
    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public ProgressBar my_prog;
    }
}
```

You can use the `ExampleAdapter` like this:

```
if(friends != null) {
    ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter(Main.this, friends);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

If you want to show a `ProgressBar` at a specific position you just do this:

```
// Shows the ProgressBar in the first row
adapter.showProgressBar(0, true)
```

Comment: and on the main activity can I set **my_prog** visibility?

Comment: Do you want to set the visibility of all `ProgressBars` in every row at once, or each row individually?

Comment: I want to set one of them when a person click an item on listview I want to hide clicked text and show just there progressbar. So I need to do that on main activity and individually when click ,

Comment: I see, I will modify the code above to suit your needs. But you are mistaken, most of the magic happens in the `Adapter`. The `MainActivity` shouldn't know too much about stuff in a `ListView`. Would just make it more complicated and potentially dangerous.

Comment: thanks for answering, so how can I do my case? I mean I have a listview , and I need to dissapear item text when a person click on that item and show progressbar on just thant item. Thanks again

Comment: Do you want only one row to show the `ProgressBar` at a time or should it be possible for multiple rows to show a `ProgressBar` at the same time?

Comment: it should be possible for multiple rows to show a ProgressBar at the same time. if its possible

Comment: it is a well done example and super thing I guess , thanks a lot!  I need to check this and understand this logic because I implement this to many events I use. I will try it know and back to you soon ,

Comment: this line **convertView.findViewById(R.id.text)** gives this error : **Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to TextView** should I user this **(TextView)** before the **convertView**

Comment: Of course, I am sorry, I forgot to cast the `Views`! I will correct it in my answer.

Comment: it is already work , thanks a lot, now I must understand it is logic thanks again.

Comment: If you have any questions feel free to ask!